# Google Cloud Function / MongoDB VM instance communication

Tags: python, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that scrapes german real estate site immobilienscout24.de. The results of this should be saved in a mongoDB database hosted on a google cloud VM instance.
Currently, I send the results via the GET request response, which of course is not optimal. How can I remotely insert data into the mongoDB VM instance using a python cloud function? How can I let different VMs remotely communicate with each other?
I also want to split the scraper function into multiple smaller ones, so I need a way for the cloud functions to communicate with each other as well. I have very little experience with Web Development, APIs, TCP/IP etc. so please be very detailed in your answer. I use PyMongo and Python3.5 on the cloud VM. To sum things up, I need a way for cloud functions to remotely communicate with VM instances (MongoDB, other python scripts) and with other cloud functions and VMs as well. Thank you!

```
mygoogleusername@mongodb-1-servers-vm-0:~$ ip a | grep net
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
inet 10.156.0.5/32 brd 10.156.0.5 scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fe9c:5/64 scope link
```

```
mygoogleusername@mongodb-1-servers-vm-0:~$ id
uid=1000(mygoogleusername) gid=1001(mygoogleusername) groups=1001(mygoogleusername),4(adm),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),1000(google-sudoers)
mygoogleusername@mongodb-1-servers-vm-0:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.27
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("d0d59151-aea7-4392-8d81-b00387876908") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.23
Server has startup warnings: 
2021-10-01T17:41:56.763+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2021-10-01T17:41:56.763+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2021-10-01T17:41:56.763+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2021-10-01T17:41:56.763+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
---
Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
```

Answer (score 0):

FIR Response:

Here is `MongoDB` with `Python` documentation that could help you on how to insert data:
https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/python-quickstart-crud/

Follow the documentation steps to use `cloud firestore` for your code:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

To connect the DB here is a code example that could help you:

```
import db from ‘./firebase/config’;

const usuario = {
     name: ‘name’,
     active: true or false,
     id : 1
    }
//insert into usuarios …

db.collection(`users`)
    .add( user )
```

After that, the user should be on your database, adding an ID for each one.

The second question on how to communicate VM instances with each other, here is a documentation that could also help you:
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations

`Install Squid` on `gateway-instance`, and configure it to allow access from any machines on the VPC network (valid subnet IP addresses). This assumes that gateway-instance and hidden-instance are both connected to the same VPC network, which enables them to connect to each other.
user@gateway-instance:~$ sudo apt-get install squid3

Enable any machine on the local network to use the Squid3 server. The following sed commands uncomment and enable the acl localnet src entries in the Squid config files for local networks and machines.
Squid link: http://www.squid-cache.org/